# Hows does TFSBuild 2013 determine which configuration to build first?

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I've had to use msbuild.exe calls within my build script instead of the MSBuild Task and I've noticed that some assemblies only appear in Debug.
What determines that the configuration is Debug first and maybe only Debug from what I can see.

I'm using the DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml.
(I'm guessing theres something in the xaml that dictates what Configuration is run first).

Also is the ConfigurationToBuild still used? I carried it over from TFS2010.

```
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Any CPU">
      <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
      <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
    </ConfigurationToBuild>
    <ConfigurationToBuild Include="Debug|Any CPU">
      <FlavorToBuild>Debug</FlavorToBuild>
      <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
    </ConfigurationToBuild>
```

Comment: TFS build will build the configuration(s) you've specified in your build definition. if you haven't specified a configuration or platform to build it will build the default configuration.

Comment: Are the properties mentioned above, ConfigurationToBuild, used any more?

Comment: are you using a TfsBuild.proj?

Comment: Yes. Migrating from TFS2010 to TFS2013 and we brought the ConfigurationToBuild along. I've added the Release|AnyCPU and Debug|AnyCPU into the Build Definition "Configurations To Build", so I dont think the ConfigurationToBuild property is even being used.

Comment: I've done a bit of searching and I think you're going to struggle to use TFSbuild.proj files in 2013. There doesn't appear to be an "upgrade template" Whilst the default template will run the file (it's just MSbuild) the old upgrade template passed through a bunch of MSbuild parameters that the default template won't. Depending on the complexity of your build it shouldn't be too difficult to use the default template to build your Solution(s) directly.

Comment: Our TfsBuild.proj is very complex. We do alot of file copies, checkouts, edits, checkins. Its the copies that are catching me out as the Paths do the project outputs is not as it used to be e.g. The BinariesRoot is different and SolutionRoot bin/Release bin/Debug may be somewhere else or the Release may not exist at all at certain times.